# Given a prime p find a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_p ^{*}$

Tags: group-theory, computational-complexity

I found this problem in the introduction of a book on computer complexity and mention that Gauss had an algorithm to solve it but he want a "better taste" algorithm in the book say that finding this algorithm is an open problem.

I took a undergraduate semester on group theory so I know a little bit of cyclic groups so I know that $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ is a cyclic group and that the order of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ is $p-1$. The problem is not really difficult from a theoretical-point of view but rather a computational problem.

So I want to know exactly what is the algorithm that Gauss made and where to find more on this subject

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes, you are correct. I will edit that.

Comment: For the multiplicative groups: ​ ​ ​ When p=5, 2 is a generator that's not relatively prime to p-1. ​ When p=11, 3 is relatively prime to p-1 but is not a generator. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Exactly, that statement is wrong, too. If the generators were the numbers coprime with $p-1$ then $2$ would never be a generator, but it clearly is, and quite often too ($\approx 30\%$ of the cases for reasonably small primes).

Comment: A long-standing open problem (Legendre's conjecture) states that $2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$ for infinite primes $p$, indeed.

Comment: @RickyDemer you're correct, I will edit that and say that some generators of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{*}$ are coprime with p.

Comment: @LuisVictoria Honestly I would just take the relatively prime comment out. I don't think it adds anything to the post and is confusing because it makes it seem like relative primality to $p-1$ might matter when it doesn't. Your current phrasing implies that if it's relatively prime to $p-1$ then it's a generator, but that's false ($p=11$, $3$ is not a generator). Sure some of the generators are relatively prime to $p-1$ but also some of them are the sum of two squares. I don't see why the first is any more relevant than the second.

Comment: @StellaBiderman thanks for the comment! I just wrote what I thought was usefull but you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we believe in the generalized Riemann hypothesis, for any prime $p$ large enough there is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$ in the first $C\log(p)^2$ elements, so a good strategy to find a generator is to apply the following test:

> For every prime divisor $q$ of $(p-1)$, check if
>   $g^{\frac{p-1}{q}}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. If that happens, discard $g$: it
>   is not a generator. If it survives till the last prime divisor of
>   $p-1$, keep it: it is a generator.

to the elements $g=2,3,5,6,\ldots$ (avoiding perfect powers) till getting a survivor.

Without strong assumptions like GRH, that is not granted to work in $O(\log^k p)$ time, but still is the best approach up to my knowledge, and it gives heuristics for believing in the truth of GRH: it works pretty good for practical purposes, and the existence of a prime $p$ with a too large smallest generator would disprove GRH.

Comment: Is this algorithm the best we know about?  or there are others that maybe use other strong assumptions?

Comment: @LuisVictoria: strong assumptions are made just to claim its complexity.

Comment: Is this algorithm the best we can made?

Comment: @LuisVictoria: I strongly believe so.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio how can I find the proof of your method ? I want to see the reason behind this method

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish [this](https://www.math.umd.edu/~immortal/MATH403/lecturenotes/ch4.pdf) is a good reference