# How to find generator of $(G,\ast)?$

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated

Let $G=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$.

An operator $\ast$ on $G$ is defined by $a\ast b=r$, where $r$ is the remainder when $4ab$ is divided by $11$ for $a,b$ in $G$. (For example $6\ast 9=7$, the remainder when $216$ is divided by $11$.)

What is the generator of $(G,\ast)$? Please explain your answer

Comment: Any thoughts?  Clearly there are not many things to try.  Have you, say, worked out which of those is the identity element?  That's a good first step.

Comment: Now you see it.i edited it again.

Comment: Please edit to include your thoughts on the problem itself. Again:  what is the identity element?  It's not $1$ since, for instance, $1*1=4$.

Comment: I can't understand please what you are saying

Comment: You don't know what the identity element of a group is?

Comment: I know it but i am not good at group theory as i think identity element is 3 am I correct

Comment: How might you show that $3$ is the identity? (that is the correct answer, by the way).  One way is to multiply each element $g\in G$ by $3$ and confirm that you get $g$ back.  Or you could look at the defining product in $G$ and try to prove it that way.  Your choice.  Either way is a good exercise in working with this group.  I suggest doing it both ways.  For larger groups, of course, only the second method really works.

Comment: But how to prove 2 is generator in this problem please help me

Comment: First do the warm up exercise.  Without knowing the identity element, it is impossible to sort out the generator.   After that, just compute $2*2, 2*2*2, 2*2*2*2$ and so on.

Comment: I will do it thank for your help

Comment: Are there any proper way to find generator?

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with trial and error.  Certainly what I'd do in this case.  Only alternative I can see is to follow the program proposed by @DietrichBurde.  That is, identify the abstract group via an explicit isomorphism and then use the known generator from the other group.  But of course that depends on knowing A, the explicit isomorphism and B. an explicit generator for the other group. In this case, I'd say that trial and error was the clear way to go.

Comment: I have no idea about this.it is ok.thank everyone

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The group $U(11)$ is cyclic of order $10$ and $g=2$ is a generator. 
How is your group related to $U(11)$?

Reference for finding a generator of $U(p)$ for $p$ prime:

[Given a prime p find a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_p ^{*}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188836/given-a-prime-p-find-a-generator-of-mathbbz-p)

Comment: You're answer is correct but I don't know how to prove it

Comment: How did you get generator as 2?

Comment: Did you read Jack D'Aurizio's answer? Start with $g=2,3,\ldots$.